# how to authenticate username/password of https site to access a file in php

Tags: php, xml, authentication, https, openssl

I want to access an xml file from https://test24.highrisehq.com/tasks/upcoming.xml using php.
Following is the sample code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://test24.highrisehq.com/tasks/upcoming.xml");
```

since the connection is secured I am getting an error:

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(https://test24.highrisehq.com/tasks/upcoming.xml)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in
>   D:\wamp\www\xml\index.php on line 3

I need to put in the username and password somewhere in the code before accessing the file. Can anyone please tell he how can I achieve this ?

Regards
Umair

Answer (score 3):

cURL, you seek [`cURL`](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1081)! (Seriously, cURL is awesome. Scroll down at that link and you'll find the HTTP Authentication example below)

```
// HTTP authentication 
$url = "https://www.example.com/protected/"; 
$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //see link below  
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  
echo $result;
```

You can find information about using `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` [here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/).

Comment: I am able to get into https://test24.highrisehq.com/ but when I try to retrieve https://test24.highrisehq.com/tasks/upcoming.xml it says HTTP Basic: Access denied. So what should I do now